# Unable to create an AWS Blockchain instance of type bc.t3.small / bc.t3.medium

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to use a bc.t3.small or medium for my NFT minting test following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/database/mint-and-deploy-nfts-to-the-ethereum-blockchain-using-amazon-managed-blockchain/) guide but I got a 400 HTTP response code telling it's invalid as size... I've tried on eu-west-1 and eu-west-2, but following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/it/managed-blockchain/instance-types/) link it should be possible... anyone has a similar issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sizes are no longer available. The current selection is (the AWS page can be outdated; wouldn't be the first time):

[image]